# App switching in UI Automation

Tags: javascript, ios, automation, instruments

Is there a way to switch between applications using UI Automation in instruments?. And also to change wifi settings using the same? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is not currently a way to change connection settings. Although, technically if you are using the simulator you could launch an external script using `UIAHost.performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout` to change the host computers internet settings.

Switching between apps is also not possible for the reason that they don't want you controlling apps that aren't yours. However, if you own both apps I suppose it'd be possible to launch an external script to launch one app in instruments and once that test is over launch the second one. This would only work in some cases though.